# Ошибка при передаче значения из TextBox в sql запрос

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  tRoutesPuncts.ID_Punct, tPuncts.sPunct FROM dbo.tRoutesPuncts INNER JOIN tRoutes ON dbo.tRoutesPuncts.ID_Route = dbo.tRoutes.ID_Route" +
       " inner join tPuncts ON dbo.tRoutesPuncts.ID_Punct = dbo.tPuncts.ID_Punct WHERE tRoutesPuncts.ID_Route=" + id.Text, connection);

        dtForAddPuncts = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dtForAddPuncts);
        bsForAddPuncts= new BindingSource();
        bsForAddPuncts.DataSource = dtForAddPuncts;
        cbAddPuncts.DataSource = bsForAddPuncts;
        cbAddPuncts.ValueMember = "ID_Punct";
        cbAddPuncts.DisplayMember = "sPunct";
    }
```

Ошибка появляется здесь : "adapter.Fill(dtForAddPuncts);"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы хоть прокомментируйте где именно у вас проблема. Видимо в присвоении адаптера?

Comment: Не надо так - напрямую в запрос какие-то поля из пользовательского ввода - дыра безопасности. Ну и наверно все же надо в кавычки взять)

Comment: ошибка возникает здесь "adapter.Fill(dtForAddPuncts);"

Comment: Пробовал взять в кавычки, не помогает:( Точнее ошибка исчезает, но в comboBox ничего не выводит. А если в sql запросе заменить текст comboBox'а и поставить определенное значение, то все идеально работает.

Comment: adapter = new SqlDataAdapter($"SELECT  tRoutesPuncts.ID_Punct, tPuncts.sPunct FROM dbo.tRoutesPuncts INNER JOIN tRoutes ON dbo.tRoutesPuncts.ID_Route = dbo.tRoutes.ID_Route" +
       " inner join tPuncts ON dbo.tRoutesPuncts.ID_Punct = dbo.tPuncts.ID_Punct WHERE tRoutesPuncts.ID_Route=[{id.Text}]", connection);   и есть новое удобное формитирование строки с помощью знака доллара

Comment: Эх,возникает ошибка System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Недопустимое имя столбца "{id.Text}"."

Comment: @Tema4910 Смотрите - все участники разговора понимают, что дело в значении `id.Text` (например, там ничего нет), но Вы упорно не хотите сказать, что за текст в этом `TextBox`-е.

Comment: @Igor Там хранится значение текущего ID_Route у таблицы tRoutes

Comment: Добавьте одинарные кавычки. А вообще, используйте параметры.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov пробовал, в данном случае не помогает

Comment: Добавьте одинарные кавычки вокруг `id.Text` в там запросе, что приведён в вопросе. А в коде в комментариях у вас зачем-то квадратные скобки вставлены - это трактуется как имя колонки, о чём прямо сказано в исключении.

Comment: Символ `$` нужно использовать и для второй конкатенируемой строки. Подсветка синтаксиса в IDE явно покажет же...

Comment: Кстати, какого типа `ID_Route` в БД? Ну, там, `int` или `varchar` или ещё что.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void LoadDataFromRoutesPuncts(int id)
    {
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  tRoutesPuncts.ID_Punct, tPuncts.sPunct FROM dbo.tRoutesPuncts INNER JOIN tRoutes ON dbo.tRoutesPuncts.ID_Route = dbo.tRoutes.ID_Route" +
   " inner join tPuncts ON dbo.tRoutesPuncts.ID_Punct = dbo.tPuncts.ID_Punct WHERE tRoutesPuncts.ID_Route=" + id, connection);

        dtForAddPuncts = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dtForAddPuncts);
        bsForAddPuncts = new BindingSource();
        bsForAddPuncts.DataSource = dtForAddPuncts;
        cbAddPuncts.DataSource = bsForAddPuncts;
        cbAddPuncts.ValueMember = "ID_Punct";
        cbAddPuncts.DisplayMember = "sPunct";
    }

LoadDataFromRoutesPuncts(Convert.ToInt32(((DataRowView)this.bsForRoutes.Current).Row["ID_Route"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Там хранится значение текущего ID_Route у таблицы tRoutes

я Вам что, Станиславский?

Напишите уже, что там за текст, а то я Вам минус поставлю.

---

`<дистанционное чтение кода сквозь монитор>`

Строка `id.Text` - пустая. Соответственно, SQL заканчивается на

```
... WHERE tRoutesPuncts.ID_Route=
```

что синтаксически ошибочно.

Давайте, мы вместо Вашей ошибки получим ошибку конвертации:

```
int ID_Route = int.Parse(id.Text);
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  tRoutesPuncts.ID_Punct, tPuncts.sPunct FROM dbo.tRoutesPuncts INNER JOIN tRoutes ON dbo.tRoutesPuncts.ID_Route = dbo.tRoutes.ID_Route" +
       " inner join tPuncts ON dbo.tRoutesPuncts.ID_Punct = dbo.tPuncts.ID_Punct WHERE tRoutesPuncts.ID_Route=" + 
       ID_Route.ToString(), connection);
```

`</дистанционное чтение кода сквозь монитор>`

Comment: Извините, что не так подробно все описал, сейчас скриншоты прикреплю:)

Comment: всё, в вопросе закинул необходимые скриншоты:)

Comment: @Tema4910 Спорим, это не тот `TextBox`, про который Вы думаете? Остановитесь в отладчике на строке `dtForAddPuncts = new DataTable();` и посмотрите, какой SQL  в адаптере. Сообщите нам результат.